# Хранение результатов SQL-запросов (Кэширование)

Tags: mysql, php, кэширование, sql

Всех приветствую.

Такой вопрос: как и где вы храните результаты SQL-запросов? Мне кажется, что не очень продуктивно каждый раз выполнить один и тот же запрос.

Answer (score 2):

Использую фреймворк, который делает такую работу за меня: [PhalconPHP](https://phalcon-docs-ru.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/models.html#caching-meta-data)

Comment: @abasov90, если можно, подскажите название. И, если не трудно, распишите где хранит результаты.

Comment: PhalconPHP https://phalcon-docs-ru.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/models.html#caching-meta-data

Answer (score 2):

[memcache](http://php.net/manual/ru/book.memcache.php)

Можно хранить не только результаты запросов ;-)

Comment: @Johny, хм, а сколько примерно занимает оперативки хранение 1000 запросов?

Comment: @evansive хранятся не запросы, а результаты наверно, а там в зависимости от того что. 1 000 страниц по 20Кб ~ 20Мб не думаю что это критично. А если все так плохо, то храните в том же MySQL, в отдельной таблице.

Comment: @evansive - или в [redis][1]

[1]: http://redis.io

Comment: @ua6xh плюсов redis'a вроде не оценить если БД не в памяти.

Answer (score 1):

В зависимости от того, насколько динамично меняются данные, можно использовать временные или базовые таблицы.

Comment: Поддерживаю. Плюс СУБД самостоятельно должна принимать решения о кэшировании и возврате соответствующих данных, если запросы повторяются. Не знаю как *MySQL*, но *Oracle* это умеет.

Answer (score 0):

Можно хранить результат в закешированных html или txt файлах в виде сериализованной строки

Comment: @mountpoint, наверно, не очень удобно..